# $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, field-theory

Prove that the set $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ of all the algebraic numbers in $\mathbb{C}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: What do you know about sums and products of algebraic numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closure under addition comes from the fact that $\alpha\in\Bbb C$ is algebraic iff

$$\dim_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb Q(\alpha)<\infty$$

Since

> $$\Bbb Q(\alpha+\beta),\Bbb Q(\alpha\beta)\subseteq \Bbb Q(\alpha,\beta)$$

we see that $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ is closed under the usual operations and has all the properties of a field. Clearly $1,0\in\overline{\Bbb Q}$, so that's pretty much that.